# Wasm Hot Reloading Experiment: Debunking Assumptions, and How to specify where the data section is?

Tags: memory, linker, webassembly, hot-reload

First, to avoid making this seem like an XYZ problem, I'd like to give some context (Note I am not using Emscripten):

I am trying to see if I can implement a form of hot reloading for Wasm programs written in C++, hosted on the web. To do this, I want to have a section of memory that I call my "world state" (to anyone who has watched Handmade Hero ( https://handmadehero.org/ ), this will be familiar):

```
struct State {
// put everything here
} state;
```

Typically for a full C++ program with a platform layer, you'd allocate this struct on the platform side and feed a pointer to that memory through a function pointer in the reloadable/dll/dylib part of the code. The reloadable code puts EVERYTHING into this persistent memory so if the code needs to be recompiled and reloaded, all the state will continue to exist since the memory was allocated in the part of the program that wasn't reloaded. As far as I can tell, this is impossible in Wasm though. 
Firstly, is my assumption correct that I have to use WebAssembly.Memory? --or can I allocate a uint8array in js and use that for my persistent state, separate from the program memory? If so, is that slower?

So this will work as long as I don't use a dynamic allocator like WASI, and instead use a push allocator I can control. (I think this because, suppose I use malloc to get memory addresses and reload--malloc's internal state will reload and think all the heap memory is available when it's not, so future allocations might clobber previous ones.) 
Upon reload, I can first copy the struct into a temporary buffer on the js side, reload, get the memory location of the struct from Wasm (I will require that it exists), and copy the saved memory from js back into position.

However this falls apart if I use pointers because if I change the program (which is the point) `__data_end` might change, which would offset all of the addresses! I checked the linker flags here https://lld.llvm.org/WebAssembly.html to see what I could control. I can specify that the stack comes before the data segment, but the heap would still come after that, which results in the same problem. I can also specify where the global data are located, but that's not the data segment I believe, so the variable-size data segment could still offset all of my addresses.
Here's a nice page that can help us visualize the Wasm memory: https://dassur.ma/things/c-to-webassembly/

Would anyone have any thoughts on how to achieve what I'd like? The only options I can think of involve somehow using memory outside the Wasm memory (possibly slower or impossible), using only stack memory and no pointers (unrealistic unless I can auto-recalculate all pointer offsets after a recompile, which would be painful and bug-prone), or finding a way to make the data segment come after the stack and heap at a fixed address, which would then guarantee that the stack and heap segments wouldn't get offset if the data segment needs to grow. Another option, if possible, would be to fix the max size of the data segment. The Wasm spec/documentation aren't really great when it comes to memory manipulation like this, so I'd appreciate some clarification about what's possible too. Lastly, maybe I could use two Wasm modules (but wouldn't that sort of indirection be slow)? I might be missing something crucial related to the memory layout.

Please let me know if you need more details. I've done something like this before in C, as I mentioned, and it's a common rapid iteration game-dev technique. Basically I'm trying to recreate it in Wasm.

EDIT: Apparently you can call Wasm functions from another module directly. Firstly, how do you do it, and secondly, what would be performance characteristics be for accessing the memory of another module?

EDIT2: Maybe some form of dynamic linking if that's supported? https://webassembly.org/docs/dynamic-linking/

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly modules hold variable state in three distinct places:

- Linear memory
- Local variables associated with the execution stack
- Global variables

Of these, only global variables and linear memory are accessible to the host environment, and potentially serialisable in order to cache them as you hot-reload your module. There is of course no way to directly access and store the current call-stack.

If I were looking to achieve this, I'd create my own state machine within WebAssembly, storing this within a known location within linear memory.

Comment: Okay, but this doesn’t directly answer my concerns. I don’t want to serialize anything other than my data struct, but the variable size of the data section might offset the addresses, which would be a problem. Then none of the locations would be “known,” yes? Is the idea to assume that the data section will have a specific maximum size (even if it doesn’t) and just start the heap at a certain known address? Then I’d create my own malloc that “knows” this. This would be much easier if I could control the location of the data section. Would it help if I drew some pictures?

Comment: Also, to clarify, I just want to know if it’s possible to specify where the data section/global data reside in the memory. The default is: [data|stack|heap]. I know you can instruct the linker to do this: [stack|data|heap], but what I need is the following, where the heap size is constant in my use case: [stack|heap|data]. Even better would be if data could be placed in a different module.

Answer (score 0):

Wasm is organised into modules, and modules define four relevant kinds of entities: functions, memories, tables, globals. The code is in the functions, while the other three represent a module's state.

Now, the interesting thing is that all four of these entity kinds can be imported and exported. Moreover, all of them can be created externally to the module, e.g., by the JS API.

Consequently, a way to emulate code swapping is to set up your module such that all three pieces of state are created externally and *imported* into the module. That way, you can keep them alive externally and pass them to the upgraded module once available. (You also need to make sure that the upgraded module doesn't use data/element segments or start functions in a way that paves over preexisting state.)

Of course, this only works if the shape of the module's state does not change between upgrades. E.g., no new globals, no new data layout in memory, otherwise the new code won't understand the old state. *That* is actually the hard part of the problem, but it's independent from Wasm specifics.

Comment: The hardest problem is dealing with pointers. If the data section changes sizes, then the heap will be offset, so if the heap previously began at address A, and I had a pointer into A, I'd be in trouble if the data section increased size because now my pointers would be directed at something in the data section. Is there a way to place the data section after the heap, or can I cap the size of the data section? Otherwise, I could assume a max size of the data section and start my virtual heap after that.

Comment: I'm afraid that's just the tip of the problem's iceberg. But in any case, Wasm doesn't know anything about your data or heap. It just gives you a linear memory space, organising it is up to you.

Comment: I thought that the data section, stack, and heap were still located in specific regions, as shown here: https://dassur.ma/things/c-to-webassembly/ (Scroll down for the image.)

Comment: @synchronizer, that's how LLVM uses the memory (and similarly other compilers/runtimes), but Wasm itself doesn't care.

Comment: So I guess the question is... is there some hidden way to get clang and the linker to put the data section somewhere else? I can only find a flag to move the stack first. It’s looking as though I’ll have to wait until dynamic linking is added. Then (if I understand correctly), I could have one persistent module handling memory and sharing that at (hopefully?) no cost with the reloadable module.

Comment: I would make any bet that there is no practical way to make LLVM support hot code upgrade safely, for Wasm or otherwise. It's a super-hard problem, and there are waaayyy too many moving parts in a complex compiler like that that isn't even designed for it. Mark Miller puts it nicely: http://www.erights.org/data/serial/jhu-paper/upgrade.html

Comment: Well if I could have the 2-modules approach, then that would work. I *think* that’s in the dynamic linking proposal but am not sure.